# In MongoDB's query, what unit is "center" "radius" in?

Tags: mongodb, database

```
> center = [50, 50]
> radius = 10
> db.places.find({"loc" : {"$within" : {"$center" : [center, radius]}}})
```

Is it 10 km, miles, feet, or meters?
Lat/long?

Comment: The same units as `center`, surely? How can it be anything different?

Answer (score 3):

I must be the same units than your data. If you store location in meters, your query will operate in meters. You have to choose what units you want to use.

I you need to use lat/long, the units for the position of your objects will be in decimal degrees and the units for the distances will be in radians. You need to use the [spherical model](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) to handle the fact that earth is round.

Comment: hey,could you give a answer of my question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224913/mongodb-not-getting-correct-result-using-geowithin-operator

Comment: More info about calculating distance in spherical geometry: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/

Answer (score 1):

They're in degrees - so 1 ~= 69 miles.