# MongoDB: Not getting correct result using $geoWithin operator

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, geospatial, spring-data-mongodb

I am using `$geoWithin` for circle, and i am not getting expected result. There are two collections,one for `users` and second for `items`. I am setting radius and coordinates for item. so i have to find a users within that coordinates and radius.

User collection

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(25287),
    "_class" : "com.samepinch.domain.user.User",
    "name":"XYZ",
    "location" : [
        74.866247,
        31.63336
    ]
}
```

Item collection

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(46603),
    "itemName" : "Chandigarh",
    "categoryName" : "TRAVELLING",
    "location" : {
        "_id" : null,
        "longitude" : 77.15319738236303,
        "latitude" : 28.434568229025803,
        "radius" : 29153.88048637637
    }
}
```

as according to item coordinates and user coordinates,there is approx 500 km distance between two places.

Query

```
db.users.find({ location: { $geoWithin: { $center: [ [77.15319738236303,28.434568229025803], 29153.88048637637/3963.2] } } } ).count()
```

According to $geoWithin,user should not show,but it is showing. If i am doing something wrong,please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is, you are searching in a far too wide radius.
According to the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/), the correct syntax of `$centerSphere` is:

```
db.<name>.find( {
    loc: { $geoWithin: 
     { 
        $centerSphere: [ [ <longitude>, <latitude> ],
        <radius in MILES>/3963.2 ] } 
     }
} )
```

You are now searching points in a 29153.88048637637 mile radius around your point, and both points are in that radius around the center you defined.

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: So what should i do if i want to search in a far too wide radius ?

Comment: you are searching in a radius of ~29.153 miles = ~46.917 km around your point. since the radius of the earth is only 6.371km, logically every point on earth will satisfy your `$geoWithin` condition. You should consider making your radius smaller.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to query related to `$geoWithin` or `$centerSphere` in future in your project then specify your field structure like this only:-

```html
"location" : {
        "lng" : 77.15319738236303,
        "lat" : 28.434568229025803
    },
"redius" : 120
```

and then do query like:-

```html
db.collection.find( {location: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ lat, lng ], radius/3963.2] } }} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Only because I have run into this a few times now, I'd like to elaborate on Ashutosh's answer.

The radius must be in radians, and the conversion is based on the sphere's radius in the units you wish to work with.  Assuming you are working with Earth as your sphere and you want your `$geoWithin` to be in meters, then you'd set the `radius` field to `meters/(6371*1000)`, or the distance you want divided by the radius of the earth in the units your distance represents.

This list should help:

- **Meters:**  distance in `meters/6371000` (earth's mean radius in meters)
- **Kilometers:** distance in `km/6371`
- **Miles:** distance in `miles/3959`
- **Feet:** distance in `feet/20903520`