# Mongodb:is it right schema design for circle query?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a requirement to find users with in specified longitude,latitude,radius. The longitude,latitude and radius will be in my item collection. so designed schema for both collection as follows,

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(25287),
    "_class" : "com.samepinch.domain.user.User",
    "name":"XYZ",
    "location" : [
        74.866247,
        31.63336
    ]
}
```

And item collection

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(46603),
    "itemName" : "Chandigarh",
    "categoryName" : "TRAVELLING",
    "location" : {
        "_id" : null,
        "longitude" : 77.15319738236303,
        "latitude" : 28.434568229025803,
        "radius" : 29153.88048637637
    }
}
```

now i am firing query as like

```
db.users.find({ location: { $geoWithin: { $center: [ [77.15319738236303,28.434568229025803], 29153.88048637637/3963.2] } } } ).count()
```

It is giving me a wrong result,please help me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: What exactly you get and what do you expect?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply,i have explained my problem here,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224913/mongodb-not-getting-correct-result-using-geowithin-operator

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query related to `$geoWithin` or `$centerSphere` in future in your project then specify your structure like this only:-

```html
"location" : {
        "lng" : 77.15319738236303,
        "lat" : 28.434568229025803
    },
"redius" : 120
```